# How should I handle if a server crash?

Tags: java, sockets, crash, server

I am wondering if I have 2 servers, one that is "main" server and the other one is just there(Both are using the same back-end code). How should I handle if main server crash and I want my clients to user the other server, making it so they don't have to restart their program or anything like that.

I've read up on using the **bully algorithm**, but I'm lost in how to handle the sockets and data(messages) that my clients have used on the first main server, and use it in my second server.

Comment: How about setting the servers in a cluster?

Comment: What do you mean with that? I'm kinda new to this with network programing

Comment: I want to know more about how you redirect data from one server to another @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Are you storing the data in database or distributed cache? If you are maintaining cache, no changes are required in application. Second server simply get the data from cache. If you are using database, you can re-load the data related of crashed server from database and continue.

Comment: Yeah It's not databased stored. But how? If my main server crash won't I lose the data? how can I send the data between the crashed server and the "new" one? @sunrise76

Comment: The distributed cache will be stored in some other machine. The machine can have active passive node too. NoSQL technology fits your business case. But which technology to chose among NoSQL options dependent on your business use case.

Comment: http://nosql-database.org/  and http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/6/20/35-use-cases-for-choosing-your-next-nosql-database.html are some good links on NoSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to implement "failover" at the application level (e.g. in your Java/sockets code). I would discourage you from doing that.

Here are some alternatives that might be *much* more robust:

- Implement a clustered web server and/or clustered database server:

  - http://blog.smartbear.com/devops/high-availability-basics-for-developers/
  - https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Suite_Overview/s1-clstr-basics-CSO.html
- Implement a proxy:

  - http://www.haproxy.org/
  - http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/High_Availability_High_Performance_Web_Cache
- High Availability for your SQL database

  - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2013/11/20/sql-server-2012-alwayson-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-design-patterns.aspx
  - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10803/toc.htm
  - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-ha-scalability/en/ha-overview.html
- Finally, to answer your original question about implementing failover at the application level, here are a few examples:

  - [Failover Socket Client (.Net)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20106/Failover-Socket-Client)
  - [Multithreaded Forward Server Example](http://inetjava.sourceforge.net/lectures/part1_sockets/InetJava-1.10-Forward-Server-Example.html)

ADDENDUM:

- You might also want to look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/): http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078565/open-source-tools/use-memcached-for-java-enterprise-performance--part-1--architecture-and-setup.html

Comment: Thank you for all the links. It turns out that my question was not asked "precisely". I'm just going to vote this as an answer 'cause it looks like alot of information that will help me solve my problem @paulsm4

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if a server crashes, there is nothing you can do about the data that was residing on it (until, of course, the server comes back up). So, if you do not want to lose data in case of failures, you should use a distributed (NoSQL?) data store (such as Cassandra, Redis, DynamoDB etc.) as they have already solved this problem in a scalable way.

Second, if your question is, 'how do I route my requests from A to B when A fails', you can frontend your servers A and B with a simple (NodeJS based, for example) proxy. Initially, the proxy will 'forward' all client requests to A. When A crashes, the proxy detects that (probably when it sees that all the forwarded requests have been timing out for the past x seconds) and switches to server B.
However, there will be a small time window (depending on your configured value of x) where client requests will keep failing.

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Answer (score 0):

1. If you store any state on your servers that you don't want to loose when a server is down then store your state on the two specific database servers - a master and a replica. If you don't know which database server to pick then let me know and I will ask you additional questions to help.
2. If a client code that is using your servers is under your control then implement all the fault tolerance logic in there. The simplest way of doing this is the "round robin" - you connect to a random server until you find a server which serves your request. Google "round robin" for more details.
3. If a client code is not under your control then you should use BGP load balancing. The main idea of that is that once a server is down another server gets the IP address of the first one, such as on a client side everything is perfect. For more details just google "bgp load balancing".